# Import each Column in CSV file to separate combox

Tags: powershell

So I have a CSV (tenants.csv) file with three rows.

```
Tenant,TenantID,Defaultdomainname
TetantA,TenantA_ID,TenantA_Defaultdomainname
TenantB,TenantB_ID,TenantA_Defaultdomainname
TenantC,TenantC_ID,TenantA_Defaultdomainname
```

I read this CSV file with function:

```
function csvread()
{
    Set-Location 'f:\Documents\SAPIEN\PowerShell Studio\Projects\AzureToolbox'
    $csvfile = Import-Csv ".\Tenants.csv"
    $List = @()
    foreach ($line in $csvfile)
    {
        $text = $line.name + ": " + $line.tenantid + ": " + $line.defaultdomainname
        $List += $text
    }
    return $List
}
```

I created a button to fill a combobox with the contents of the CSV:

```
$BTN_tentantrefresh_Click = {
    csvread | ForEach-Object { [void]$CMB_Customer.Items.Add($_) }
}
```

The result is the combobox fills up with the CSV readings.

However I'd like to fill 3 separate comboboxes like this:

- Tenantname ends in Combobox: CMB_Customer
- Tenantid ends in Combobox or textbox: CMB_Tenantid
- Defaultdomainname ends in Combobox or textbox: CMB_Defaultdomainname

Also I'd like to have its index changed. So when I choose an item from the list, all 3 boxes get updated.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the whole code. Why not import using `-Delimiter :`? Would erase your need for the `foreach` loop

Comment: You can add a range of values to a combobox if I recall - you dont have to add one at a time with aloop. Not able to test right now, but adding $csvfile.name to the Combo list for example should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComboBox.Items` has an [`AddRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_ObjectCollection_AddRange_System_Object___) method that accepts an array.

There is an easy way to create an array from a property for each element of an object array (which is your CSV data) - simply use dot notation like `$arrayOfObjects.PropertyName`. Much easier than writing an explicit loop.

Put together your code could look like this:

```
$BTN_tentantrefresh_Click = {
    $csv = csvread
    [void]$CMB_Customer.Items.AddRange( $csv.Tenant )
    [void]$CMB_Tenantid.Items.AddRange( $csv.TenantID )
    [void]$CMB_Defaultdomainname.Items.AddRange( $csv.Defaultdomainname )
}
```

For the 2nd question please create a new post, if you can't find an existing answer.